# long delay to connect to vpn with network-manager

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04 and since then it takes ages to connect to vpn (vpnc) from the network-manager.

First, I hit this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1448724) which makes nm-applet unavailable at startup. After starting it manually when I click on the vpn I want to connect to I don't get prompted to enter my password until 2-3 long minutes.

Any solution?

Comment: Can you ensure that this happens with any VPN service and is not a problem with the specific VPN you are using?If it is problem with specific VPN, then we cannot do anything. If it is a problem with Ubuntu, then you should post a bug report on launchpad. bug reports are off topic here.

Comment: The two vpns I have setup in my network-manager behaves the same way since I upgraded. There were ok the day before.  I suspect there is a configuration clash or something.